# Translation using Google Api

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

this is the code i am using to translate from English to Vietnamese.

```
     NSString *urlPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/translate_a/t?client=t&text=%@&langpair=en|vi",txt_view.text];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithScheme:@"http"
                                      host:@"translate.google.com"
                                      path:urlPath];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;

NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

if(error == nil)
{
    NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Result : %@", result);

    NSArray *arr = [api tocanizeTheString:result tocan:@","];
    result = [arr objectAtIndex:0];
    result = [api replaceStringwithString:result strTobeReplaced:@"[" stringReplaceWith:@""];
    result = [api replaceStringwithString:result strTobeReplaced:@"\"" stringReplaceWith:@""];

    txt_view.text = result;   // here i get only translated data...
}
else 
{
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}
```

some times it give accurate result and sometimes it doesn't. please tell me whats the problem.

"My name is Taimur Mushtaq" i type this in my app, it shows correct result which is "Tên tôi là Taimur Mushtaq".

"I am a good boy" the result should be "Tôi là một chàng trai tốt". instead it is "tôi là m\u1ED9t c\u1EADu bé t\u1ED1t"

Comment: Please tell us more about the problem. In detail, what are the results you expect and what are the actual results?